# How to convert JSON to POJO with ManyToOne relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that is structured with a bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship with another entity. Here's how it looks:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer foo_id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID")
    Set<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer bar_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID")
    Foo foo;
}
```

How do I save a `Foo` object with the `bars` set using a `CrudRepository`? So, for example, I deserialize this JSON into a `Foo` object:

```
{
    "foo_id": 1,
    "bars": [{"bar_id": 1},
             {"bar_id": 2}]
}
```

I need to set the `Foo` variable somehow?

If I need to use separate `save()` function calls for each `Bar`, then is there a way to start a transaction so all these insert operations are atomic?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should map the relationship like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
Set<Bar> bars;
```

The cascade type will depend on your needs. Read this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) for further information on cascade types.

Then, you can save the Foo entity like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<>();
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setFoo(foo);
bars.add(bar);
foo.setBars(bars);
fooRepositoy.save(foo);
```